# Вывод значения из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Приветствую, имеется 2 таблицы.

1) id, login, role (role - одно из чисел из id_r)

2) id_r, flag

Значение flag - текстовое (пользователь, админ и т.д.)

Как составить запрос, который выведет логин и роль в текствовом виде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT first_table.login, second_table.flag 
FROM   first_table 
JOIN   second_table
    ON first_table.role = second_table.id_r
```